# Set tck to vector of values in R

Tags: r

I am wanting to set the tick marks on the x axis of a plot to change length (from 0.015 to 0.02) every 5th tick position, but tck won't accept more than one value, any ideas? Here is an example of my code:

```
year<-seq(1960,2010,1)

xlab.pos <- rep (NA, length (year))
xlab.pos [seq(1, length (xlab.pos), 5)] <- year [seq(1, length (year), 5)]

xlab.tck <- rep(0.015, length (year))
xlab.tck [seq(1, length (xlab.tck), 5)] <- 0.02

plot(0, 0, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n",
xlim = c(min(year), max(year)),ylim = c(0, 5000))

axis(1, at = seq(min(year),max(year),1), labels = xlab.pos, tck = xlab.tck)
```

But as expected I get the error: graphical parameter "tck" has the wrong length
I can't figure out how to set it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using package `Hmisc` will help you out.

```
library(Hmisc)
plot(0, 0, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n",
     xlim = c(min(year), max(year)),ylim = c(0, 5000))
axis(1, at = seq(min(year),max(year),1), labels = xlab.pos, tck = -0.015)
minor.tick(nx = 3, ny = 0, tick.ratio = -1/2)
```

You'll need to do a bit of extra tweaking though!